# Placing a <div> under an <h1> title in a <section>

Tags: html, css

I currently have an html section like this:

```css
.projhero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.projcard {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects projhero" id="projects">
  <h1> Title </h1>
  <div class="card-grid">
    ........
  </div>
</section>
```

However when I do this the Title appears beside the contents of the div (the div contains cards in a grid to represent books) however I want the title to appear at the top when I enter the section and the grid of cards underneath.

I tried various CSS techniques from YouTube and chatgpt however none helped

Comment: Did you mean .projhero to be flex-direction: column?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```css
.projhero {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
}

.projcard {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
}


/*testing boxes*/

.box {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects projhero" id="projects">
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <div class="card-grid">
    <div class="box">Box</div>
    <div class="box">Box2</div>
    <div class="box">Box3</div>
    <div class="box">Box4</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just add `flex-direction: column;` to the projhero style

```css
.projhero {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 24px;
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.projcard {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="projects projhero" id="projects">
  <h1> Title </h1>
  <div class="card-grid">
    <div class="projcard">Card</div>
    <div class="projcard">Card</div>
    <div class="projcard">Card</div>
    <div class="projcard">Card</div>
  </div>
</section>
```